# Multigroup Path Analysis using Lavaan in R - wrong number of arguments in modifier

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I'm working on a simple multigroup path model (test of moderated mediation) in lavaan and getting an odd error.

Here is my model:

```
model <-'
MC ~ c(c1,c2)*RA
RP ~ c(a1,a2)*RA
MC ~ c(b1,b2)*RP'
```

When I go to use check the model using the lavaanify command, like this:

```
lavaanify(model)
```

I get the following error:

```
  lavaan ERROR: wrong number of arguments in modifier (c1,c2) of element MC~RA
```

I've also tried using the model with the sem command itself (while specifying a grouping variable) and get the same error.

Can anyone help me along the path here?

Thanks!

Ryan

Comment: `lavaanify(model, ngroups=2L)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to help.

Comment: In what way does it not work ... it returns the model table

Comment: @user20650 I get this error: `Error: unexpected ',' in "lavaanify((model,"` I'm starting to think this may be some sort of corrupt installation or other error. I've never had these problems before.

Comment: you have an extra opening bracket --- strangely makes it throw an error. Remove this and it works

Comment: @user20650 That seems to work. Odd that it throws an error, but thanks!